# Count result of Sub-query and Use it in Query

Tags: mysql

I have two Tables information_business and business_likes.

**Table-1** :- information_business has fields `id , name , address , dt_added` etc.

**Table-2** :- business_likes has fields `id , business_id , user_id , status(1=> like , 0 => unlike)`

If Someone like a business I'm inserting new data in business_likes table as a business_id, user_id and status = 1 and if the same person dislikes than that row are updated.

Now my question is **I want to select all the business with the highest count of likes is first and lowest count of likes is last.**

If any business has zero counts then all the businesses with zero counts are in last.

I tried so many queries but nothing works for me.

**Query:**

```
SELECT *, (SELECT COUNT(status)
FROM business_likes) AS business_likes_count
FROM `business_likes`
LEFT JOIN information_business ON information_business.id = business_likes.business_id
ORDER BY business_likes.id
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this sql: you can use `group by on business id` and `ORDER BY business_likes_count DESC` if you want highest value to come first.

```
     SELECT information_business.*,COUNT(status) as business_likes_count FROM `business_likes` JOIN information_business 
ON information_business.id= business_likes.business_id group by  business_likes.business_id ORDER BY business_likes_count DESC;
```

Comment: Yes I will when SO allow me ;)

Comment: this doesn't select businesses with zero count. If any business has zero counts then all the businesses with zero counts are in last. It only select business with count.

Comment: then you can change the ` join to left join` and use `group by  information_business.id` and try.